# Problems with Ruby versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber

I am learning Ruby and have to do some homework, but have problem with executing code. I searched this forum and Google and found that this could be problem with different Ruby versions but I don't know how to fix this. I've tried to execute:

```
cucumber features/filter_movie_list.feature
```

and got this:

> And I should not see 'G'                            #
>   features/step_definitions/movie_steps.rb:32
>         no such file to load -- rspec/matchers/built_in/has (LoadError)
>         ./features/step_definitions/movie_steps.rb:34:in `/^(?:|I )should not see '([^']*)'$/'
>         features/filter_movie_list.feature:37:in`And I should not see 'G''

Can someone help me to solve this problem or give me link to solution?

EDIT:
movie_steps.rb relevant for this taks is:

```
Then /^(?:|I )should not see '([^']*)'$/ do |text|
  if page.respond_to? :should
    page.find('#movies').should have_no_content(text)
  else
    assert page.find('#movies').has_no_content?(text)
  end

end
```

Comment: Can you be more clear on what you ought to do?

Comment: I edited question. But I found solution. Solution was adding rspec gem to Gemfile.

Comment: What `Gemfile`? Are you using Rails? As you can see, your question was not at all clear to the audience. Try to fix it by adding an answer yourself, and accept it later then ...

Comment: @mliebelt, sorry I forgot to mention Rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message says that Cucumber can't find RSpec.

To solve it, edit your Gemfile and add these and that should solve it.

```
group :test do
  gem 'rspec'  # Behavior Driven Development (BDD) for Ruby
  gem 'rspec-core'  # RSpec runner and example groups.
  gem 'rspec-expectations'  # RSpec matchers for should and should_not.
  gem 'rspec-mocks'  # RSpec test double framework with stubbing and mocking.
  gem 'rspec-rails'  # RSpec version 2.x for Rails version 3.x.
end
```

If that does solve it, you can probably remove all those lines except the first one (the 'rspec' one) because that line should take care of the others.